# How to use receivers in Go?

Tags: pointers, go, struct, receiver

There are two code samples as follows.

**Sample 1:**

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Dat struct {
    Num int
}

func (d *Dat) Fn1a(i int) {
    d.Num = i
}

func (d *Dat) Fn2a() {
    d.Num++
}

func main() {
    var d Dat
    d.Fn1a(1)
    d.Fn2a()
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

**Sample 2:**

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Dat struct {
    Num int
}

func Fn1b(i int) *Dat {
    d := &Dat{i}
    return d
}

func (d *Dat) Fn2b() *Dat {
    d.Num++
    return d
}

func main() {
    d := Fn1b(1).Fn2b()
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

Both samples output the same results.

My question is about the difference between these samples. I could notice the following difference.

Although in Sample 1, `type Dat struct` can be changed to `type dat struct`, in Sample 2, when `type Dat struct` is changed to `type dat struct`, golint shows a warning: `exported func Fn1b returns unexported type *main.dat, which can be annoying to use`. So in Sample 1, `dat` can be used directly as a `struct` without being public.

Are there any other differences? For example, which is better?

Thank you so much for your time and advices. And I'm sorry for my immature question.

Comment: "when `type Dat struct` is changed to `type Dat struct`" --- is it a typo here?

Comment: @zerkms Yes. I have mistaken it. 
That is "when type Dat struct is changed to type dat struct".

Comment: The main difference between those two examples is, in my opinion, that `Fn1a` modifies an existing value, while `Fn1b` allocates and returns a new value. As to which is better, that depends entirely on your use case.

Comment: ＠mkopriva Thank you for your advices. What each function do you think is appropriate for what case?

Answer (score 1):

There are some different topics inside your question:

**1) Exported and unexported types**

If you have a function, which is exported and that function returns an unexported type this will cause to an error, when you call that function outside of your package.

So let's say that it is not allowed to make your type `Dat` unexported.

**2) Which solution is better?**

That depends on, but at all it would be sample 2. You see how much cleaner your main function is. If your struct will be more complicated you can do some stuff there. For example your struct has a parameter which is a map you need to initialize that map by using `make()`. In sample 1 you need to do this every time you create a new Dat type.

Normally you would call that function `NewDat()`. If you always use that function when creating a new Dat variable that makes your code also more flexible for changes.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I think that I could understand the difference of these. I would like to create a function to initialize struct, use sample 2. If I don't want to use ``Dat`` as public, namely I want to use ``dat``, how should I do? Although I thought that I return int, which isn't struct, using interface, it cannot be used like sample 2. In the case like sample 2, is it no problem even if ``Dat`` is public? I'm sorry the basic question.